# Adding functions to php native classes?

Tags: php, javascript, web

In javascript, we can edit the prototype of objects like string and numbers and simply "add functions" to already existing native classes.

I was wondering how do we "add functions" to already existing php native classes (like strings etc) ?

Comment: By the way, there isn't a string class in PHP. It's a primitive data type.

Comment: @BoltClock k cool, thx for the info =D

Comment: For user-defined classes, there is runkit: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.runkit.php ... but you can't modify built-in classes with this. In my opinion it's not good practice, anyway ... if you want to extend a (native) class, just *extend* it ;-)

Comment: By way of clarification, the same is true of most other built-in types (e.g, strings, numbers, arrays, file handles, *etc*). PHP was originally designed without classes, so most of its basic functionality is **not** object-oriented.

Comment: @harald no no, you are missing the point. I wanna do this: `"a string".Action()`. we can do this in javascript and in vb.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in PHP. You can only [inherit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) from the existing classes (if they're not [final](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php)) and add methods to the subclasses.

Comment: I'd thought *dynamic* PHP is supposed to have this feature. Dang, even vb.net allows us to add methods onto already existing classes without subclassing it

Comment: @Pacerier: Extension methods in C# and VB.NET don't actually modify the original classes, even though it looks as if they do. But good point.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems more in line with OOP to extend a class through inheritance anyway.